# Call elements of an Linq executed stored procedure

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures

I created a Linq to SQL class in C#.
Take the stored precedure in the dbml file.
Added a new Datasource (Type Object).

So i want to take the value of an Table that my Linq returns.

```
LeasinggesellschaftDataContext blabla = new LeasinggesellschaftDataContext();

            blabla.getDetails(2);

            MessageBox.Show(blabla.Gesellschaft.ElementAt<Gesellschaft>(0).Gesellschaftsname.ToString());
```

LeasinggesellschaftDataContext = class from the dbml file.
getDetails = stored procedure.
Gesellschaft = the returned table of the sp.

i want the value of the column "Gesellschaftsname".

Can anybody tell why the ElementAt Methode is not working ?

_______Edit___________

I had take the tips from you and make an Variable, see the code below:

```
        LeasinggesellschaftDataContext blabla = new LeasinggesellschaftDataContext();
        ISingleResult<getDetailsResult> returnset = blabla.getDetails(2);
        getDetailsResult lala;

        lala = (getDetailsResult)returnset;
        MessageBox.Show(lala.Handelsregister.ToString();)

        foreach (getDetailsResult result in returnset)
     {
      MessageBox.Show(result.Handelsregister);                
     }
```

SO the "next" Quesion is. Why the foreach work and the Access by lala not ?

### This Code Below Works

```
        LeasinggesellschaftDataContext blabla = new LeasinggesellschaftDataContext();
        ISingleResult<getDetailsResult> returnset = blabla.getDetails(2);
        getDetailsResult lala;

        lala = returnset.First();
        MessageBox.Show(lala.Handelsregister.ToString());
```

Comment: It would help if you'd say in what *way* it's not working. Note that a simpler way of calling ElementAt(0) is to use First()

Comment: blabla.getDetails(2) is my stored Produre with give me the Table of Columns. I want to call an value from the return columns.

Comment: Change lala = `(getDetailsResult)returnset;` to `lala = returnset.First();` and you should be happy.

Comment: And So Albin made one Person happy, definitely :-) now works great for me. Thanks to Jon Skeet and Albin Sunnanbo. I will update the right code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`returnset` is not of type `getDetailsResult`, it is of type `ISingleResult<getDetalsResult>`, so casting `returnset` to `getDetailsResult` will throw an exception.

As Albin Sunnabo says, assign `lala` the value of `returnset.First()` and you will be able to use it, so long as there is a result. the `First` extension method will return the first result of your stored procedure.

```
getDetailsResult lala = returnset.First();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need parentheses after the stored procedure: `blabla.Gesellschaft().`

Comment: blabla.getDetails(2) = this is my stored Procedure with an int parameter.

Comment: Why don't you store that in a variable and use that variable in the  MessageBox statement then?

Comment: Tip taken and implemented, look at Question